# Compare 2 doubles but without all the digits on C

Tags: c, compare, double

I want to compare 2 double but without all the digits.
for example i have this double 1.548799778 and this 1.547990978 and I want to compare 1.xx from each. How can I "round" this double to 1.xx?? 
Thanks

Comment: What sort of rounding do you want? e.g., round-up or round-down?

Comment: @AdrienPlisson : I deleted my post ... thanks for your explications

Comment: Do you want to round or do you want to trunc?

Comment: i have a double 1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(20) and I want to make it 1.xxxxxxxxxxx(11)

Comment: Do you wan to compare for equality only or also for order, like less than?

Answer (score 5):

One technique will be using the `trunc` function like this:

```
double d1, d2;
d1 = 1.548799778;
d2 = 1.547990978;
if (trunc(d1*100) == trunc(d2*100)) {
   // do your thing
}
```

Using `100` because you want two decimal places. You can use other numbers if you want more or less decimal places.

Comment: do i need to import any lib for that? cause its say trunc is invalid in C99

Comment: i tried it with 10000000000 in order to get 1.xxxxxxxxxxx but i get xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx

Answer (score 4):

to compare that `x` and `y` are near enough, something like

```
(x==0.0 && y==0.0) || fabs(x-y)/max(fabs(x),fabs(y))<1e-6
```

to round `x` use `floor(x)` or `ceil(x)`  as suggested by Jan Vorcak

*Addenda*: I'm not sure that it will work for [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (the details give headache)

Comment: Instead of "x == 0 && y == 0" i would use simply "x == y", is faster if the two numbers are equals.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to just use a comparison with tolerance.

```
 if (fabs(a - b) <= tolerance) { .... }
```

choose your tolerance on how much precision you want.

For example, you can choose tolerance to be 0.001 to use about the first 2 digits.

Comment: might not work very well if both `a` and `b` are tiny numbers, like `1e-6` and `2e-6` with tolerance being `1e-5`. See my answer for a better suggestion.

Comment: Yes, this uses absolute tolerance and your method uses relative tolerance, but the problem as exposed is solveable to me using just this method, it wants only a small number of digits, it seems 2, so in this case, this method should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

use [floor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor/) or [ceil](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/ceil/) function from math.h

Answer (score 0):

The following might have the fastest execution time, and it's useful as a general comparition of floating point variables.

```
if (  x-y < 0.01 && x-y > -0.01 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Math.h` functions

```
double check(double number)
{
    if (modf(number, 0) >= .5)
        return number >= 0 ? ceil(number) : floor(number);
    else
        return number < 0 ? ceil(number) : floor(number);
}

double round(double number, unsigned int places)
{
    double off = pow(10, places);
    return check(number * off) / off;
}

if(round(1.548799778, 2) == round(1.547990978, 2))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be considerably fast and configurable if needed. no additional inheritance is introduced

```
int compare(double a, double b)
{
    static const double PRECISION = 0.0001;
    if (a < b)
        return b - a < PRECISION ? 0 : 1;
    else
        return a - b < PRECISION ? 0 : -1;
}
```